# How do I set email attribute on cloud only environment of Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365

I don't have sync infra or local AD at all, also I do not have exchange online service.

the email attribute in Azure AD is grayed out.

any idea?

Comment: Email address is for Exchange, you can use `Alternate email` (editable via Azure AD portal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Email** attribute changes as the **User Principal Name** changes.

But if you don't have Exchange online license, it's not allowed to fill in this attribute.

So if you need to use an attribute to represent the email and want to retrieve it in the code, using **Alternate email** is an option to consider as @robby suggested.

Comment: Tnx! Any other workaround? I still can find some users with email which doesn't have exchange online licence

Comment: @ItzikTzadaka Can you share where you see some users with email which don't have exchange online license? Any screenshots? User Principal Name is also displayed as a mailbox format.